# I disabled the animation on a unwind segue and it works on the simulator but still appears on the device

Tags: ios, swift, segue, uistoryboard, unwind-segue

So the other day i was really scratching my head because i couldn't get the "no animation" working a unwind segue until i tried it on a simulator and not a actual device and it worked there and then i ran the identical project on a device and the animation is still there? I already posted a question here: [How to perform unwind segue without animation?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34483891/how-to-perform-unwind-segue-without-animation) and i tried running the project posted as an answer and the same thing happend, worked on a simulator didnt work on a device. What should i do? Does anyone have experience with that? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Updated to 9.2 and it works now.